# Can a device driver written in or compiled to LLVM IR?

Tags: linux, driver, llvm, llvm-ir

The reason i am interested is that there is an everlasting problem with linux and proprietary drivers. Why hardware vendors do not ship their drivers in LLVM IR form?

Comment: what problem would that solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write Linux device drivers in user mode code.  I have seen demonstrations written in Python (handy for prototyping).

Presumably your idea is that hardware vendors could ship a LLVM IR driver, and then the driver would work with x86, ARM, or anything else?  Most hardware vendors are not interested in niche-markets, and only want to support their hardware on particular platforms that they have tested on.

There is very rarely any interesting IPR in a driver (although there may well be in the library on top of the driver).  If vendors wanted to support multiple platforms, they could just ship C code with instructions to build, and a restrictive (or even GPL) license.